# Urn Ball Game - $m$ urns $n$ players Expected number of rounds the game to be played to get all the players selected

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, reference-request

This is an urn-ball game. There is a coordinator and there are $m$ urns and $n$ players.  Each player has one ball each. The game happens in rounds.

In a specific round the users throw balls at random in to the $m$ urns. Those balls which uniquely occupies an urn (i.e only one ball in an urn) will be selected by the coordinator along with the corresponding player.

Say for example in the first round if $k$ balls out of $n$ balls uniquely occupies $k$ urns and the rest of the $n-k$ balls are occupying urns with more than one ball then those $k$ balls along with the $k$ players will be selected by the coordinator and removed from the rest of the rounds.

The game will move on to the next round with $n-k$ players and $m$ urns. The game will continues like this until the coordinator selects all the players.

**We have to find the following parameters:**

1) The Expectation of the number of throws (rounds) a player has to play until he is selected by the coordinator

2) The Expectation of the number of rounds the game has to be played so as to get all the $n$ players selected.

Can some one help me getting the solution for the above problem. If you can provide some references also it would have been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If $n \ll m$ you have the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) but you draw in lots of $n$ because relatively few balls will go in a bin with another.  This is an extremely useful model for your problem.  If $m \ll n$ it will be rare for a ball to be alone in a bin, so you can compute the expected time to have a ball alone.  If $m \approx n$ things are very difficult.  The idea of the coupon collector analysis still applies, but the dispersion on the number of single balls makes it a mess

Comment: Thanks Ross. I will look into the the limiting cases. But as of now I need more information on $m≈n$ case. If you can provide some specific references it would have been really helpful.